# is there an equivalent for max() in mysql that takes custom values?

Tags: mysql, aggregate-functions

observe the table

| id | priority | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | high | x |
| 1 | med | k |
| 1 | low | y |
| 2 | med | k |
| 2 | low | x |

I need a function that returns id and value with the highest priority present in the table so it should return x for 1 and k for 2 here. is there any way to do it without creating an intermediate table with a helper column and using max over that?

Comment: If you use MySql 8 you can use analytic window functions.

Answer (score 0):

Using `row_number` you can easily accomplish provided you are using MySql 8+

```
select Id, value 
from (
    select *, 
    Row_Number() 
      over(partition by id 
        order by case priority 
          when 'high' then 1
          when 'med' then 2 
          else 3 end
      ) pri
    from t
)t
where pri=1
```

You'll have better performance if you define your priorities as *integer* values instead of *strings*.